# Asynchronous confusion

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-datastore, es6-promise

I have some big stuff going on.
I have a function that looks more or less like this:

```
// Yes, that is the head of the function. Isn't it great?
// But I noticed in hindsight now, I don't need async, actually :(

async sync() {

  doSomeSynchronousNormalStuff();
  if (shitHappens)
    return Promise.reject('Some bad stuff happened here.');

  // some helper functions and thingies here:

  toBeCreatd = [];
  toBeUpdated = [];
  beingCreated = [];
  beingUpdated = [];

  // We can only save 500 things in datastore at once
  // So first we queue them up, and then save in chunks of 500 as they are ready
  // datastore.save and datastore.get return promises

  _queueToCreate = (newThing) => {
      toBeCreated.push(newThing);
      if (toBeCreated.length>=500) {
          beingCreated.push(datastore.save(toBeCreated.splice(0, 500))).then(() => console.log('saved some new things; hooray!')););
          console.log("gonna save some new thingies");
      }
  }
  _flushCreateQueue = () => {
      while (toBeCreated.length>0)
          beingCreated.push(datastore.save(toBeCreated.splice(0, 500)).then(() => console.log('saved some new things; hooray!')););
          console.log("gonna save some new thingies");
  }

  _queueToUpdate = (newThing) => {
      toBeUpdated.push(newThing);
      if (toBeUpdated.length>=250) {
          beingUpdated.push(saveUpdate(toBeUpdated.splice(0, 250)));
          console.log("gonna save some updates");
      }
  }
  _flushUpdateQueue = () => {
      while (toBeUpdated.length>0) {
          beingUpdated.push(saveUpdate(toBeUpdated.splice(0, 250)));
          console.log("gonna save some updates");
      }
  }
  _saveUpdate = (chunk) => {
      return datastore.get(chunk.map((tbu) => tbu.key))
      .then((oldThings) => {
          updates = [];
          for (i=0; i<chunk.length; i++) {
            updates.push(getDiff(chunk[i], oldThings[i]));
          }
          return chunk.concat(updates);
      })
      .then(datastore.save).then(() => console.log('saved some updates; hooray!'));
  }

  return datastore.runQuery('get me some keys and timestamps of old things')
  .then((oldKeysAndTimeStamps) => getAllFreshStuffPagewiseFromAPI((pageOfFreshStuff, index) => {
      console.log('Got page ${index} of fresh stuff');
      pageOfFreshStuff.forEach((maybeNewThing) => {
          oldIndex = oldKeysAndTimeStamps.findIndex((old) => maybeNewThing.key === old.key);
          if (oldIndex != -1) {
            oldThing = oldKeysAndTimeStamps[oldIndex];
            if (oldThing.timestamp < maybeNewThing.timeStamp)
              _queueToUpdate(maybeNewThing);
          } else {
            _queueToCreate(maybeNewThing);
          }
      });
  )
  .then(() => {
      console.log('----\nAPI calls all done.\n----');
      _flushCreateQueue();
      _flushUpdateQueue();
      return Promise.all(concat.apply([], beingUpdated, beingCreated));
  });
}
```

Something is strange here, though:

The `getAllFreshStuffPagewiseFromAPI` function can take a very long time, iterating through lots and lots of pages. It will return a promise that resolves when all the things have been fetched from the API.

A good amount of idle time is to be expected here, due to API call per-time limits (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket).

Through the queuing and flushing mechanisms in place, many `datastore.save` calls are being issued during that time already, and promises to their results stored in the `beingUpdated` and `beingCreated` arrays.

I expected that some of those `datastore.save` promises should already be fulfilled while things are still being fetched from the API. However, it seems that the `datastore.save` calls only really get going once the API calls are finished.

In other words, I only ever get to see something like:

```
...

Got page 1336 of fresh stuff
gonna save some new thingies
Got page 1337 of fresh stuff
gonna save some updates
gonna save some new thingies
-----
API calls all done.
-----
gonna save some updates
gonna save some new thingies
saved some updates; hooray!
saved some new things; hooray!
saved some updates; hooray!
saved some new things; hooray!
saved some new things; hooray!

...
```

And the `saved some new XY; hooray!` messages do come rather rapidly, once they have started. But they don't start before `API calls all done`. I expected that they should.

Is there a reasonable explanation for this?

Thanks for any hints, and may the force be with you.

Comment: To prevent hogging system resources or running out of resources, node.js has some internal limits on some things and will queue operations to avoid too many resources being used.  It is possible something like that is happening with either your http requests or any file I/O that might be involved in database access.  That could explain why not everything runs in parallel like you think it was going to.  If a usage limit is reached, then other requests go in a queue until the first ones have finished.

Comment: I honestly don't know what kind of operations are behind many of your calls so I can't really say for sure on any of this, but it's one possible explanation.  In some cases, internal limits can be increased (such as http requests in parallel) and in other cases, you can reorder how your operations work to better optimize.